# Magento Credit Card Payment method form not showing up in one page checkout

Tags: magento

My site's onepagecheckout credit card method is not working. When I choose Credit Card(save) or Credit Card(authorize.net) the cc form is not loading. Paygate at the backend is also enabled. Check/Money order is working fine. But issue is with both cc methods not showing up. Any idea on this? Thanks in advance.